# How to add a loading animation to my website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add an animation to my website which would load when someone clicks any button on my website. The animation will be shown till the next page loads.

I want it to be done using JavaScript only. Is it possible?

I have no idea how to do this.

PS: Check this link for an example.
https://photos.app.goo.gl/tmh2KnPfcxPcVXkS9

Comment: https://loading.io/progress/ as examle. Keep in mind, that seeing a loading bar is normally a sign that a website has been poorly programmed as it needs to laod to much content then necessary or that it isnt optimized for mobile use.

Comment: @tacoshy I can't understand... Even if the site is optimised then also it will take atleast some time for the loading depending on the internet connection. So a loading animation could be shown in between that time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sites that do this best are [single page apps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA) that aren't actually navigating between pages per se. They're staying on the same page and fetching and displaying new content with javascript (colloquially referred to as "[ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX)"). This approach is very common with modern js tools like [React](https://reactjs.org), [Angular](https://angularjs.org/), and [Vue](https://vuejs.org/).

Without navigating away from the page, these apps throw up a loading animation and kick off a request for new content behind the scenes. Once the new content is loaded and ready to display, they remove the animation.

Assuming you don't want to get into all that and just want to navigate between pages, you could add a click [event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) on links that displays your animation.

Here's a quick example that isn't pretty but demonstrates the basic idea. (The link doesn't actually point anywhere, but it could, of course.)

```js
function showAnimation () {
  document.body.classList.toggle('loading');
}

document.querySelectorAll('a[href]').forEach(a => a.addEventListener('click', showAnimation))
```

```css
body.loading::after {
  content: 'loading animation here';
  position: fixed;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  color: white;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-content: center;
  animation: loader 2s infinite;
}

@keyframes loader {
  from {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  to {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
   <a href="#">Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo can hide an show any element as example below a Spinner icon from Font awesome Icon libary.

```
<button onclick="start_loader()">Click Me</button>

<i class="fa fa-spinner" id="loader"></i>

 function start_loader() {
    var x = document.getElementById("loader");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "";
     } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
 }
```